# Saving data from a data grid view with search functionality to a database

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, wcf

Currently I'm using WPF and WCF. WCF handles most of the database end and is the server, while WPF is the client I'm using. On the WCF end I have:

```
    public DataSet getAllFixedCostsName(string name)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd;

        if (name == null || name == string.Empty)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From FixedCost", con);
        }
        else
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From FixedCost Where FixedCostName = " + name, con);
        }

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds, "FixedCost");

        return ds;
    }

    public void UpdateFixedCosts(DataSet ds)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From FixedCost", con);
            SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            SqlCommandBuilder cmdbl = new SqlCommandBuilder(adap);

            adap.Update(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: '{0}'", e);
        }
    }
```

On the WPF end I have:

```
public void SearchFixedCost_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox search = _contentGrid.Children.OfType<TextBox>().First();
        DataGrid dataGrid = _contentGrid.Children.OfType<DataGrid>().First();
        ds = new DataSet();

        if (_contentGrid.Children.OfType<RadioButton>().First().IsChecked == true)
        {
            ds = cln.getAllFixedCostsName(search.Text);
        }
        else if (search.Text.All(char.IsDigit))
        {
            ds = cln.getAllFixedCostsExpenses(search.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            ds = null;
        }

        if (ds != null)
        {
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables["FixedCost"].DefaultView;
            dataGrid.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }

    public void UpdateFixedCost_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cln.UpdateFixedCosts(ds);
    }
```

The data will update successfully if I don't search for anything specific. For example, if I load the program and click search it will generate the all the rows for that table, if I update one of the rows and save, then no crash and the changes will be pushed to the database.

If I search for a specific row, then change that row and save it. I will crash on the WCF side when it reach the "adap.Update(ds, "FixedCost")", I get a System.ServiceModel.FaultException. The crash only occurs if I make a change to that row, or rows of specific data.

Comment: what is the exception on the wcf side? put the update code between a try catch and see what the exact exception is at that point.

Comment: Change from : sda.Fill(ds, "FixedCost"); To : sda.Fill(ds);  You created a new DataSet that doesn't have any tables so you cannot update a table that doesn't exist.

Comment: I would be interested to know what a `SqlCommandBuilder` does when provided a query that executes a stored procedure. It probably errors when the dataset has pending changes. And how do you expect your "get" procedure to update the database?

Comment: @RieKumar no add it on the wcf side not wpf side

Comment: I added the try-catch and got that same exception, ServiceModel.FaultException. I changed the sda.Fill(ds, "FixedCost") to just sda.Fill(ds) and it crashes at the same point. As for the stored procs, I changed them to normal sql statements and still get crashes.

Comment: Edit your question and add what your code looks like now. What do you mean "normal sql statements"?

Comment: @CodingYoshi Okay, so I added in the WCF side this time and I got "Update unable to find TableMapping['Table'] or DataTable 'Table'.", with the exception thrown being 'System.InvalidOperationException'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your update method on the wcf side, put this code:

```
adap.TableMappings.Add("Table", "FixedCost");
```

In your `getAllFixedCostsName` method you are telling it to fill the data into a table named "FixedCost". In the update method you create a new `SqlDataAdapter` but that adapter does not know anything about "FixedCost". So it is looking to update a table named "Table" in your database. It cannot find it, so it is complaining.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks :)